# Magento - Storing all images on cdn not my hosting server

Tags: image, hosting

I am new to magento and i have just starting setting up my first sites. One of the requirements i am after is to store all images files on a seperate server from which the site is hosted on. I have briefly looked into amazon cloudfront and the following plugin:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cloudfront-cdn.html

This works alongside my cloudfront distribution setup so the images are being accessed from the cdn alongside the js,css etc when i check the source. My issue is they still reside on my own server too.

Is there a way to have everything just on a cdn so that my server disk space can be kept as low as possible with only the template files on there, no images?